# How to produce a reproducible column of random integers in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, uniqueidentifier

I have a table of patient, with a unique patientID column. This patientID cannot be shared with study teams, so I need a randomised set of unique patient identifiers to be able to share. The struggle is that  there will be several study teams, so every time a randomised identifier is produced, it needs to be different to the identifier produced for other studies. To make it even more complicated, we need to be able to reproduce the same set of random identifiers for a study at any point (if the study needs to re-run the data for example).

I have looked into the RAND() and NEWID() functions but not managed to figure out a solution. I think this may be possible using RAND() with a seed, and a while loop, but I haven't used these before.

Can anyone provide a solution that allows me to share several randomised sets of unique identifiers, that never have the same identifier for the same patient, and which can be re-run to produce the same list?

Thanks in advance to anyone that helps with this!

Answer (score 0):

Your NEWID()  should work as long as you have correct datatype.

Using UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as datatype should be unique across entire database/server.  See full details from link below:
sqlshack.com/understanding-the-guid-data-type-in-sql-server

```
DECLARE @UNI UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @UNI = NEWID()
 
SELECT @UNI
```

Comments from link:

As mentioned earlier, GUID values are unique across tables, databases, and servers. GUIDs can be considered as global primary keys. Local primary keys are used to uniquely identify records within a table. On the other hand, GUIDs can be used to uniquely identify records across tables, databases, and servers.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Is there a way to make the values an integer rather than the typical format with letters and dashes included?

Comment: I should note that as far as I am aware, SQL has no standard way to produce random or pseudorandom numbers, which are usually provided by the specific DBMS.  (This question was tagged with `sql` rather than a tag for a specific DBMS, such as `tsql` or `sql-server`.)

Comment: It is possible, but not easy and may not be 100% accurate if there is a high load and will require a lot more work and logic than just using the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER (thats why it was created pretty much to be unique across all tables, databases, and servers.  Is there a reason why you want an INT?  Why not use what is built in for this purpuse?

Comment: The article I linked to above goes into all the details and reasons why to use this dataype for your situation instead of INT or other data types.

Comment: actually it might be okay using this datatype. However, I am confused how this approach would allow different sets of random IDs to be created for each study ,whilst allowing the same results to be re-produced when the query is re-run for a single study.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "allowing the same results to be re-produced"?  Do you mean copying existing Ids over to a new table?  You can do that just by copying them from the other table, just dont use NEWID(), copy value from existing table to new one.

Comment: The solution I need is for one query to be able to produce a random set of IDs for new studies, where the random ID for a patient is different to the ID produced for other studies. But for existing studies, I need the query to be able to produce the same set of randomised IDs that was produced for it initially (e.g. if a seed was used).

Comment: For the random ID this will work.  For your 2nd part you need to be able to produce same set of randomized ID's, I am still not clear, but if you need same ID's from a table that already exists, you can just select from that table.  I think you have 2 different questions here.  The first one was random IDs that this will do.  The 2nd one you should open a new question and write some code with the UNIQUEIDENTIFER column and show (with data examples) what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use the `patientid` as a seed to `rand()`:

```
select rand(checksum(patientid))
```

This returns a value between 0 and 1.  You can multiply by a large number.

That said, I think you should keep a list of patients in each study -- so you don't have to reproduce the results.  Reproducing results seems dangerous, especially for something like a "study" that could have an impact on health.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Unfortunately the code will be publicly available so we do not want to use the patientID in the randomisation process, as it effectively then becomes a pseudonym. We only reproduce the results if a specific study needs to go back to the data and make changes/updates - this way we ensure that the patients are the same

Answer (score 0):

This is too much for a comment. It's not black and white from your description and comments what you are asking for, but it appears you want to associate a new random ID value for each existing patients' ID, presumably being able to tie it back to the source ID, and produce the same random ID at a later date repeatedly.

It sounds like you'll need an intermediary table to store the randomly produced IDs (otherwise, being random how do you guarantee to get the same value for the same PatientID?)

Could you therefore have a table something like

```
create table Synonyms (
  Id int not null identity(1,1),
  PatientId int not null,
  RandomId uniqueidentifier not null default newid(),
  Createdate datetime not null default getdate()
)
```

`PatientId` is the foreign key to the actual Id of the Patent.

Each time you need a new random PatientId, insert the PatientIDs into this table and then join to it when querying out the patient data, supplying the RandomId instead. That way, you can reproduce the same random Id each time it's needed.

You could have a view that always provides the most recent RandomId value for each PatientId, or by some mechanism to track which "version" a report gets.

If you need a new Id for the patient, insert its Id again and you are guaranteed to get the same Id via whatever logic you need - ie you could have a ReportNo column as a sequence partitioned by PatientId or any number of other ways.

If you prefer to avoid a GUID you could make it an int and use a function to generate it by checking it's not already used, possibly a computed column with an inline function that selects top 1 from a numbers table that doesn't already exist as a RandomId... or something like that!

I may have completely misunderstood, hopefully it might give you some ideas though.